# How to get the selected row data from clrDgSelected and provide selected data to another datagrid in a second url page in Clarity

Tags: vmware-clarity

> I want to get selected datagrid row data from one html page and provide to another html page
>
> > both pages are in the same Clarity UI application and both have datagrid's to display the data that
> >
> > > that can be selected. See example code of first html to get data from below.

DNS Name
      App ID
      Requester
      Data Center
      Product
      Load Balancer
    
       {{element.name}} 
       {{element.csiAppId}} 
       {{element.requester}} 
       {{element.dataCenter}}     
       {{element.product}} 
       {{element.loadBalancer}}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please format your question and code properly, so it can be understood by our members. Specifically use a code block for the code and remove the unnecessary indentation in the body of the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Datagrid row selections are stored in an array on the application side.

e.g

```
<clr-datagrid [(clrDgSelected)]="selected">
  <-- ... -->
  <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let user of users" [clrDgItem]="user">
    <-- ... -->
  </clr-dg-row>
  <-- ... -->
</clr-datagrid>
```

`selected` is the application array and two-way binding keeps it in sync with what a user selects vs what may be pre-selected when data is retrieved from the server.

I would look at preserving the info in the selected array so it can be shared across multiple routes. If you have more questions or want to discuss a working application create a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team) app that shows what you are trying to do. It will help me to help you if I can look at a running application.

Comment: I have 2 components : load-balancers.component and modify-vip.component.

Comment: I have 2 components : load-balancers.component and modify-vip.component. I have a Datagrid in the load-balancers.component.html and a Datagrid in the modify-vip.component.html. I have the load balancer datagrid displaying data from a JSON file, which I can select each row and display the selected data in a module that is display when I perform a click command on a button located on the load balancer page. My problem is I don't know how to get the data to the modify-vip.component.html page to show the user the selected data from the load balancer html that was selected.